# I cant invoke javascript from functions on a different class

Tags: ios, cordova, webview, modal-dialog

I have a project where I try to invoke some JavaScript from an Objective-C class. It works if everything is in one class (I can call the script).

However, when I bring another class in the mix, I can't seem to invoke the JavaScript of the WebView of the first class. I thought I wasn't calling the class correctly, but I made my invokeJS method just bring up an Objective-C AlertView and it worked. So I know that it is calling the method, but the JavaScript does not seem to work if I call the method from the second class.

```
   [t invokeJS];
```

And in my other class

```
 -(void)invokeJS
 {
 [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"dan()"];
  }
```

Am I not allowed to invoke an action on another class's views?

I should note this is a phonegap app so this is the reason for the rather awkward setup.

I  have a modal controller in which when I dismiss the controller I want to invoke the JavaScript.

I tried to directly access the webview from my modalViewController class, but that does not seem to to work either

```
    [t.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"dan()"];
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
 STARImageController *modalView = [[STARImageController alloc] initWithNibName:@"STARImageController" bundle:nil];
  modalView.myImage = fileContents;
  [self.viewController presentModalViewController:modalView animated:YES];
```

The above code is from my toast class (t) that presents the modal view controller. It might be worthy of note that my Toast class is not a view, but rather a child class of CordovaPlugin yet I am not sure it should matter...

Comment: `self.webView` would be referring to the `webView` property of whatever class you're calling that method from... when you launch the modal controller, are you setting its `self.webview` property to be the webview on the original view controller?  How are you getting into the modal view controller, can you include that code?

Comment: added at the bottom thank you

Comment: make what you said an answer it worked=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do `[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"dan()"];` from the modal view controller, try this:

```
STARImageController *modalView = [[STARImageController alloc]   
   initWithNibName:@"STARImageController" bundle:nil];
modalView.webView = self.webView; // <-- this line
modalView.myImage = fileContents;
[self.viewController presentModalViewController:modalView animated:YES];
```

The assumption here is that the `webView` you want to run the JavaScript on is referred to as `self.webView` on the ViewController it's on, and that the modalView you're presenting has a `UIWebView` property called `webView`.

Now, `modalView.webView` is a reference to the original webview, so calling `[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"dan()"];` from the `modalView` is actually going to be calling it on the `webView` in the original view.

Comment: ah you saved me. (New to ObjC) I can pass entire views as properties to controllers as well as data? Pretty insane concept. Thanks for the help you are a lifesaver.

Comment: You're not actually passing the entire view.  You're passing a reference to the view.  There's only one webview.  And `self.webView` is a pointer to the webview.  All you're doing is copying the pointer into the other view controller.  And you can do this for any object you want.

Comment: If you wanted, you could pass a reference to an entire view controller... (which is what you're doing when you send `self` as an argument, typically as the delegate, for example with a `UIAlertView`)

Comment: can i pass the super class as well? in this case the super would be the cordova plugin class, if I was able to do that I could pretty much  command the universe (ba ha ha) no really I could do some cool things with PhoneGap quite easily

Comment: You probably don't have a reference to the super class.  You can pass a reference to the `webView` on your view controller, because you've already instantiated it.  You can pass a reference to the view controller itself (using `self`) because you've already instantiated it.  Any object you're instantiating (literally anything), you can pass a reference to it.  (And you can get to that objects methods as well as its super classes methods just as you normally would).